# How to use JavaScript variables in Jinja2, e.g. for accessing a list entry?

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

is there the possibility to implement something as follows using Jinja2?

In my `<script>`:

```
    function get_word() {
        let entry_number = 0;
        let g = "{{ words[" + entry_number + "] }}"; 
}
```

I have a list words. I want to access the `entry_number`th key of that list.  `entry_number` is a js variable. The way I try to achieve this doesn't work as
`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: list object has no element entry_number`. So it doesn't use the value of `entry_number` but looks for the entry `entry_number` which obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja will be rendered on the server. js will be executed on the client.
This `"{{ words[" + entry_number + "] }}";` is not a jinja variable. So Jinja will not parse it.

But you can pass the words list (as a jinja variable) to the client and use it in your js code.

Example inline script:

```
<script>
  const words = {{ words | tojson }};
  ...
  function get_word() {
    let entry_number = 0;
    let g = words[entry_number];
    ...
  }
  ... 
</script>
```